# Типы полиморфизма

Tags: c#, ооп

Какие бывают типы полиморфизма в C#?

Comment: Старайтесь задавать более детальные вопросы, приводить контекст и источники. Например, если бы вы сами привели список типов полиморфизма и спросили, какие из них поддерживаются, вопрос вряд ли был бы закрыт.

Answer (score 10):

Какой-то матан от программирования, но ладно, давайте пройдёмся по пунктам статьи [Полиморфизм в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)).

- **Ad-hoc полифорфизм** (перегрузка функций, приведение типа) — поддерживается, можно создать несколько методов с одним именем и разными аргументами, примитивные типы могут неявно приводиться.
- **Параметрический полиморфизм** (обобщённое программирование) — поддерживается, можно создать полиморфные (обобщённые) типы.
- **Полиморфизм включения** (наследование) — поддерживается, есть интерфейсы, наследование классов, одиночная и множественная диспетчеризация. Примитивные типы неполиморфны.